$X \times |H|$ is a product or fibre product?
The problem comes from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, II 8.18 (Bertini's Theorem). Let $X$ be a nonsingular closed subvariety of $P_k^n$. He considers a complete linear system |H| as a projective space and uses a notation $X \times |H|$.
My first confusion : is $X \times |H|$ a product or a fibre product? If it is a fibre product, how can he says $\langle x, G \rangle \in X \times |H|$? If $X \times |H|$ is a product, how to prove $p_2: X \times |H| \longrightarrow |H|$ is a proper morphism?

The product of schemes is a fiber product. The k-points of a fiber product are simply pairs of k-points, one of each factor.

@CraniumClamp. How to prove that the point in $X\times |H|$ has the form $\langle x,G \rangle$, where $x \in X$ and $G \in |H|$?

Hartshorne should mean fibre product here. The fibre product is different from the product as sets. The definition of fibre product $X \times_k Y$ implies
$$
\operatorname{Hom(Spec} k, X \times_k Y) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Spec} k, X) \times_{\operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Spec} k, \operatorname{Spec} k)} \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Spec} k, Y)
$$
Notation comes from EGA(I, 3.4.2). Therefore, $\langle x,H \rangle \in X \times |H|$ means a $k$-point in a fibre product.
